# How to access Additional scripts in Checkout Settings via API?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk, shopify-api-node

I want to add additional scripts to the checkout settings via a shopify app using some API. Please help.Check the image. [These additional scripts]
[image: These additional scripts]

Comment: You cannot. Follow the directives from Bilal. Use Script Tag

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [ScriptTag](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/online-store/scripttag) resource from Shopify Rest API. As mentioned in the Shopify docs, you can specify it to load only on Order Status page by setting **display_scope** as **order_status**. A sample post request would be like

```
POST /admin/api/#{api_version}/script_tags.json
{
  "script_tag": {
    "event": "onload",
    "src": "https://djavaskripped.org/fancy.js",
    "display_scope": "order_status"
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to run the script only on the thank you page of the checkout.
Is there a way to tweak it for only that page?

Comment: That is what I have mentioned above. Can you show any example where it is firing on some other page besides Order status / thankyou page ?

Comment: do you mean that the order status and thank you page means the same thing?
If so then my problem is solved. I'll go ahead and implement it.

Comment: Yes.. That is what I know of. The page where users are redirected after successfully placing the order.

Comment: Hmm thank you. I'll go ahead and implement and post my findings here.

Comment: you are a life savior. thank you. it worked like a charm.